# UITableView cell duplicates

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on my first Swift app, and stuck on a bug forever. When adding a new entry to the coredata, everything goes fine the first time. However, with additional items, the previously added item is duplicated in the table.

The data is not duplicated, only the cell. When the app is reloaded, the cells are displayed correctly.

Here's the code that populates the cells:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let fetchedSections: AnyObject = fetchedResultController.sections as AnyObject? {
        return fetchedSections.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let fetchedSections: AnyObject = fetchedResultController.sections as AnyObject? {
        return fetchedSections[section].numberOfObjects
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let lookup = sortedArray[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObjectID
    let spot = spotsDict[lookup] as! Spots
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SpotCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! SpotCell

    println(sortedArray)
    println(spot)

    cell.spotLabel.text = spot.title

    cell.spotPhoto.image = self.imagesDict[lookup]

    cell.distanceLabel.text = self.distanceStringDict[lookup] as NSString! as String

    cell.spotPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    cell.spotPhoto.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please include your logic around `sortedArray` and `spotsDict` - how do they relate to you fetched results controller? Are you using your own sorting instead of using `sortDescriptors` on the fetched results controller?

Comment: If you use a fetched results controller for the table view then you should not have additional data source arrays. Use `fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)` instead. Also note that your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` only evaluates the index path *row*, but ignores the *section*.

Comment: @johnpatrickmorgan I'm attempting to do relative distance sorting, so the sort key isn't stored in coredata. I've kind of pieced it together, and it's definitely beyond my skill-level, so excuse the mess. Here is the view: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andrevvm/SnarlySwift/master/SnarlySwift/SpotsViewController.swift?token=AAtTVSfjjqGRG_2Y1gbdcNgNVMj-Qwmrks5VhBB-wA%3D%3D

Comment: OK. I've rewrote the code to batch update the relative distance in core data on load, and using sortDescriptors to sort. Seems to be working well, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! @johnpatrickmorgan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem was in my sorting method.. simplified the code a lot, and sorted with sortDescriptors instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your code

`let lookup = sortedArray[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObjectID`

with below code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

`let lookup = sortedArray[indexPath.section] as! NSManagedObjectID`

Comment: i think thats not the issue

Comment: Have you added more than 2 object and see what happens?

Comment: i once had the problem on firing button action while having two sections in tableview.. i resolved that dequeing two cells from storyboard...

Comment: This has just caused all of the cells to display the same data.

Comment: @RajeshMaurya yes, after the first object, it always duplicates the previously added one. so after adding the 3rd, the 1st and 2nd are both shown twice.

Comment: It is because you are passing row rather than section.

Comment: @AndrewMcCarthy did  rajesh solve your problem? if not may be your two sections are reusing the same cell..so getting the dublicate data

Comment: Let me clarify.. upon load, the data is sorted and displayed correctly with no duplicates. It is only adding items that the duplicates happen. And there is no duplicates in the sorted array, just the table cells.

If I close the app and reload, the duplicates go away.

Comment: Does your problem is solved? Or it is still showing duplicate data? Try adding more data 10 or 20.

Comment: @RajeshMaurya, no this does not solve the issue, it makes it worse.

Comment: can you provide your project quick?

Comment: This was the issue for mine.  I know this is a post from a long time ago, but thanks!

Comment: @JakeAlsemgeest Welcome.